# Print first part of Exception to user from System.Net.WebException

Tags: c#, exception

Is it possible to only print the first part of a System.Net.WebException? I want to use it to print the first part such as:

"The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable."

And skip all the rest, is this possible somehow?

Answer (score 4):

```
Exception.Message returns a string
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what i wanted!!